# Angular RxJS: Merging the results of 2 observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have 2 Observable and I wish to see if both end up being "true". The http get observal never fires though?

```
    const storeAuth = this.store.isLoggedIn$;
    const heartBeatAuth = this.http.get<boolean>('/api/auth/heartbeat');

    return merge(storeAuth, heartBeatAuth).pipe(
      map((a, b) => {
        if (a && b) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return false;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

merge does not emit an a and b like that, use combineLatest if you want both results at the same time. Merge will emit the first result from either stream then the next.

```
return combineLatest([storeAuth, heartBeatAuth]).pipe(
      map(([a, b]) => {
```

combineLatest emits an array so you can destructure a and b out of the array with `[a, b]`

No http requests will be fired until something subscribes to the returned observable.